# Why does the string inside println method show twice?

Tags: java, while-loop, system.in

In the following code why does the string inside println method shows twice.What should I do to show the message once per iteration

```
package practicejava;

public class Query {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        System.out.println("Guess a capital letter Character");
        while ((char) System.in.read() != 'S') {
            System.out.println("wrong.guess again to finish the program");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When a user writes in console characters, to confirm fact that his input is ready to be passed to application he presses <kbd>enter</kbd> key. But console doesn't pass only provided characters, it also adds to input stream (System.in) OS dependent [line separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) character(s) after it. Some OS use `\r` or `\n` (those are single characters, `\x` is just notation to represent them) others like Windows use `\r\n` (two characters) sequence as line separator.

Now those additional characters are also read by `System.in.read()` and since they are not equal to `S` `System.out.println("wrong.guess again to finish the program");` is executed additional time.

To avoid such problems instead of working with raw data via `System.in.read()` consider using classes meant to make our life easier like `java.util.Scanner`

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Guess a capital letter Character");
String response = sc.nextLine();
while(!response.equals("S")){
     System.out.print("incorrect data, please try again: ");
     response = sc.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Safer would be `while(sc.hasNextLine() && !(response = sc.nextLine()).equals("S"))`. Otherwise a ctrl-D on Linux or ctrl-Z on Windows would make it go into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the first char that you read is the letter you typed, and then there is a second loop where the character is the line return.

For example on my linux machine, if I input "E" and then press enter,  the first loop processes the char 69 'E', and then there is a second loop to process the carriage return (char 10).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use a `Scanner` to get the user's input:

```
package practicejava;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Query {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        char c;

        do {
            System.out.println("Guess a capital letter Character");

            c = s.next().charAt(0);

            if (c != 's') {
                System.out.println("Wrong! Guess again to finish the program.");
            }
        } while(c != 's');
    }
}
```

`s.next()` will get the input from the user as a string and `s.next().charAt(0)` will return the first character in that string.